# Kornshell If statement not working

Tags: bash, if-statement, ksh, string-comparison

So I'm new to kornshell and i can't get my if statement to work. This what I have in my file

```
if $1 = "Y"
then
    echo "I am here";
fi
```

And when I execute the file this is the error that I get:

```
test.ksh[1]: Y: not found [No such file or directory]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`if` must be followed by a command; it tests whether the command terminates successfully or not.

You can use the command `test` or the equivalent command `[`, or the ksh builtin `[[`:

```
if test "$1" = Y
```

or

```
if [ "$1" = Y ]
```

or

```
if [[ $1 == Y ]]
```

The above commands succeed if the condition indicated by its arguments is true. `man test` should provide you with a list of valid conditions. Remember to quote your variable substitutions for the `test` and `[` commands; if not, undefined variables will be substituted with nothing (i.e. they will be deleted) which usually an error report.

If you don't need strict Posix compatibility, use the `ksh` built-in `[[`, which is also available in `bash`. It is more convenient because it does not word-split its arguments, so variable expansions don't need to be quoted. Note that with `[[`, the right-hand side of the comparison `==` is a pattern ("glob"), unless it is quoted, so you might need quotes on the right-hand side if you need a literal equality check.

Comment: ksh has a built-in test command named `[[` -- if you use it you must pass `]]` as the last argument. Within double brackets `=` and `==` are actually pattern matching operators, so you can test if a word *starts with* "Y": `if [[ $1 == Y* ]]; then`. Quotes around the variables are not strictly required within double brackets because "Field  splitting and file name generation are not performed on the words between [[ and ]]" -- ref ksh(1) man page

Comment: @glennjackman: good point, I was trying to be too general. I'll edit.

Comment: @glennjackman There should be a faq with this question. I know that I've frequently answered variants on it.